# Angular 11 - how to convert html to jpeg image

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-canvas, wkhtmltoimage

I tried using following code

```
const element = document.getElementbyId('myid'); // it takes little long to render
htmlToImage.jpeg(element, { quality: 0.95 })
      .then((dataUrl) => {
        console.log(dataUrl); // this prints only data:,
})
```

As dataUrl is blank image is blank.
So I tried using htmlToCanvas

```
 html2canvas(element).then(function (canvas) {
      // Convert the canvas to blob
      canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
    
  })
```

but i am getting an error
`Error loading image http://localhost:4200/`

Ho to convert HTML element to an image file?

Comment: var node:any = document.getElementById('myid');
    htmlToImage.toPng(node)
      .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = dataUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
      });
  }

Comment: u are using html-to-image Pacakge??

Answer (score 5):

Step 1 – Create a new Angular 11 app
Step 2 – Install html-to-image Package
Step 3 – Add HTML into a view file
Step 4 – Add code in Component .ts file
Step 5 – Run Angular app

```
<div id="image-section">
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</div>
 
<button type="button" (click)="generateImage()">Create Image</button>
```

ts=>

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as htmlToImage from 'html-to-image';
 
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-new-app';
 
  generateImage(){
    var node:any = document.getElementById('image-section');
    htmlToImage.toPng(node)
      .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = dataUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: I am already doing the same but dataUrl is empty (data:,)

Comment: https://angular-ivy-qxxsk7.stackblitz.io/

Comment: I realized the issue- my element(getElementbyId ) takes time to render, so dataUrl is empty